# ReactNative export 'default'.'interpolate' (imported as 'Animated') was not found in 'react-native-reanimated'

Tags: react-native, expo

Hi Guys I'm trying to make a drawer using React Navigation. The problem is, that I'm having an error that I'm not able to fix

When I run expo everything displays ok in the web

[image: Web render]

But in console this warning is displayed

[image: Console error]

When I try to render it on Android this appears

[image: Error Android 1]
[image: Error Android 2]

I have checked my version from react-reanimated

this is my babel.config.js

```js
module.exports = function(api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ['babel-preset-expo'],
  };
};
```

this is my App.js

```js
import React from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, View,Text, } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createMaterialTopTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/material-top-tabs';
import {createDrawerNavigator, DrawerContentScrollView,DrawerItemList, DrawerItem,} from '@react-navigation/drawer';

function Feed() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Feed Screen</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

function Article() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Article Screen</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

function CustomDrawerContent(props) {
  return (
    <DrawerContentScrollView {...props}>
      <DrawerItemList {...props} />
      <DrawerItem label="Help" onPress={() => alert('Link to help')} />
    </DrawerContentScrollView>
  );
}

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

function MyDrawer() {
  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator
      useLegacyImplementation
      drawerContent={(props) => <CustomDrawerContent {...props} />}
    >
      <Drawer.Screen name="Feed" component={Feed} />
      <Drawer.Screen name="Article" component={Article} />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <MyDrawer />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

And this is my overlay.js

```js
function _extends() { _extends = Object.assign ? Object.assign.bind() : function (target) { for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) { var source = arguments[i]; for (var key in source) { if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(source, key)) { target[key] = source[key]; } } } return target; }; return _extends.apply(this, arguments); }
import * as React from 'react';
import { Platform, Pressable, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import Animated from 'react-native-reanimated';
const {
  // @ts-expect-error: this is to support reanimated 1
  interpolate: interpolateDeprecated,
  interpolateNode,
  cond,
  greaterThan
} = Animated;
const interpolate = interpolateNode ?? interpolateDeprecated;
const PROGRESS_EPSILON = 0.05;
const Overlay = /*#__PURE__*/React.forwardRef(function Overlay(_ref, ref) {
  let {
    progress,
    onPress,
    style,
    accessibilityLabel = 'Close drawer',
    ...props
  } = _ref;
  const animatedStyle = {
    opacity: interpolate(progress, {
      // Default input range is [PROGRESS_EPSILON, 1]
      // On Windows, the output value is 1 when input value is out of range for some reason
      // The default value 0 will be interpolated to 1 in this case, which is not what we want.
      // Therefore changing input range on Windows to [0,1] instead.
      inputRange: Platform.OS === 'windows' || Platform.OS === 'macos' ? [0, 1] : [PROGRESS_EPSILON, 1],
      outputRange: [0, 1]
    }),
    // We don't want the user to be able to press through the overlay when drawer is open
    // One approach is to adjust the pointerEvents based on the progress
    // But we can also send the overlay behind the screen, which works, and is much less code
    zIndex: cond(greaterThan(progress, PROGRESS_EPSILON), 0, -1)
  };
  return /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement(Animated.View, _extends({}, props, {
    ref: ref,
    style: [styles.overlay, overlayStyle, animatedStyle, style]
  }), /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement(Pressable, {
    onPress: onPress,
    style: styles.pressable,
    accessibilityRole: "button",
    accessibilityLabel: accessibilityLabel
  }));
});
const overlayStyle = Platform.select({
  web: {
    // Disable touch highlight on mobile Safari.
    // WebkitTapHighlightColor must be used outside of StyleSheet.create because react-native-web will omit the property.
    WebkitTapHighlightColor: 'transparent'
  },
  default: {}
});
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  overlay: {
    ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)'
  },
  pressable: {
    flex: 1
  }
});
export default Overlay;
//# sourceMappingURL=Overlay.js.map
```

I have tried to find multiple solutions and nothing is working please help !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you have tried it yet.

The "entry point" in your input file can be the index.js or the App.js file. Make sure you add the following:
`import 'react-native-gesture-handler;` at the beginning of the file, that there is nothing else before that import. And make sure you have react-native-gesture-handler installed as describe here in this [documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/7.x/drawer-navigator#installation)

And in your `babel.config.js` file put it like this

```js
module.exports = function (api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ['babel-preset-expo'],
    plugins:[[['react-native-reanimated/plugin']],],
  };
};
```

Uninstall the app from the emulator or device where you are testing it, reinstall it and try to start it with this command
`npm start -- --reset-cache` or with `npx expo start -c` to clear the app cache.

Comment: Thanks for your help Quimbo, this worked so well, you saved my life

Answer (score 1):

While working on react-native-reanimated, you need to add a plugin in the **babel.config.js** file like this ,

```js
module.exports = function (api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ['babel-preset-expo'],
    plugins: [
      'react-native-reanimated/plugin',
    ]
  };
};
```

After that Delete all your node_modules ,after that install it again by running

```js
npm install
```

After that re-run your code by using ,

```js
npm start //{or}
expo start
```

Now your expo project will work perfectly.

Comment: Hi Vala thanks for your help

I've done what you have told me 

-Add plugins to babel config
-Delete node modules folder
-Install npm

But still is having the same errors and behavior, i have edited the post and added the overlay.js file (which is the file showing the error) i don't know if it could be useful for you

Thanks in advanced